# How to block everything from being indexed except sitemap.xml

Tags: web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, robots.txt

I want to block everything and index sitemap.xml file alone. So I do it as shown below:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /sitemap.xml
Sitemap: https://example.net/sitemap.xml
```

However, I am not sure whether this is correct or allowed.

Comment: Why would you tell crawlers where all of your pages are and then block them from crawling them? That makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: @JohnConde i get it now. Actually your answer leads me to the definition of sitemap. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove these three lines from robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /sitemap.xml
```

and give search engines the freedom to access all public facing pages so that the odds of your useful content being in their indexes are much higher.

If you leave your setup the way it is, then search engines will only attempt to access to sitemap.xml (which doesn't render as an actual webpage users can use), and all other content which includes images on your server won't be looked at by search engines that respect robots.txt